# Reading from files and store it into textboxes

Tags: php, html, file

This is my file data

```
Alex-10/9/2008-male-123456789-jaowat@gmail.com-helal@@@@
```

What i want to do is that store every string seperated by '-' and store it into HTML textboxes:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="Alex" 
<input type="text" name="date of birth" value="10/9/2008" />
```

So far i have tried this. This 'Alex' and '10/9/2008' should be read from the upper mentioned file. I could managed to store different strings into array. But i have no idea how to put these values into different textboxes. Below, is my php code where i tried to read from a file and strode values into array

```
$myfile = fopen("records.txt", "r");///This is my file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $line=fgets($myfile);
    $array = explode("-",$line);
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you do anything with `$array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$array` must contain something like this:

```
Array([0]=> Alex, [1]=>10/9/2008,[2]=>male, .......)
```

So, username Alex is stored in `$array[0]` and date of birth 10/9/2008 is stored in `$array[1]`

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $array[0]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="date of birth" value="<?php echo $array[1]; ?>" />
```

Comment: My array contails value like this:

Helal10/9/2008male123456789jaowat@gmail.comhelal@@@@